# New User ID in new Apple MDM push certificate

Tags: certificate, push, mdm

A year ago we received an MDM certificate, issued an MDM push certificate and started using it.
The MDM push certificate expires on September 15th.
We have generated a new MDM push certificate in advance.

When trying to send an MDM push using a new MDM push certificate, we get an error: TopicDisallowed.

In the new MDM push certificate, the User ID has changed (com.apple.mgmt.External....), which is used in the MDM user profile (Topic).

If we use a new User ID, then we will have to rewrite it in the MDM user profile, and all MDM users will have to reinstall the MDM profile.

Can you please tell me if it is possible to generate a new MDM push certificate with the old User ID so that all MDM users do not have to reinstall the MDM profile?

If this is not possible, then what is the command to send users with the old User ID in the profile a new profile with a new User ID?

Thank you.

Comment: Problem solved.

In the Apple account, where MDM push certificates are generated, it was necessary to press not the "Create certificate" button, but "Renew" (on the required certificate).

Then the User ID remains the same.